# Give styling to the input's entered text html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code snippet like below.

```css
.place_class input[type="text"] {
  Line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: left;
  width: 73%;
  color: #000;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="place_class" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
```

This for some reason doesn't seem to work..

Is this correct?

Comment: The class of the `input` is `.place_css`, while in the css you used `.place_class`, is this a typo?

Comment: oh that was just a typo in this question here. Still doesn't work

Comment: Try my answer, or maybe because the L in `Line-height` is uppercased instead of lowercased

Comment: Browser possibly will understand that. They even understand typos of the attributes as well.

Comment: my answer didn't work because I thought the right one was `.place_css` and not `.place_class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.place_class input[type="text"]` with `input[type="text"].place_class`

Also Line-height should be line-height

Answer (score 0):

```
.place_class input[type="text"] { // here you need to remove class .place_class
  Line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  ....
}
```

[Check this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpbOOK)

Comment: What? Didn't get you?

Comment: first of all you class name is not same in css and html. second you don't need to use both class name and element name. remove one of them will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.place_class {
  line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: left;
  width: 73%;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="place_class" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
```

Comment: can't keep the first option as I wish to only apply to a single textbox.. Second option isn't working..

Comment: try the second one again, I thought the right one is `.place_css`, not `.place_class`

Comment: Only specifying class without input type would assume that you want to use this class on something else than an input text. Check my answer.